# MySQL query that deletes all rows from A table where the id is not found on B table?

Tags: php, mysql

In my mySQL database, under the table `audience` there is a column called `unique_hash` where it has unique identifiers for each of my visitors.

In the table `behaviour` there is a column `unique_hash` and `page`. A `unique_hash` can have many rows, contrary to the `audience` table. However, the `unique_hash` found on `behaviour` are from the visitors that already saved them into the `audience` table.

Unfortunately for some maintenace reasons, I lost some of my data, and the result is that the distinct number of `unique_hash` in table `behaviour` are more than the `unique hash` of `audience`, the time that this should be equal.

What is the mysql query that will delete all the rows in the `behaviour` table where the `unique_hash` are not found on the `audience` table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`NOT IN`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparison-operators.html#function_not-in) like the following:

```
DELETE FROM behaviour 
WHERE NOT unique_hash IN (
    SELECT DISTINCT unique_hash FROM audience
)
```

A second solution would be to use [`NOT EXISTS`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/exists-and-not-exists-subqueries.html):

```
DELETE FROM behaviour
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT * FROM audience 
    WHERE audience.unique_hash = behaviour.unique_hash
)
```